# Using ViewPager with ListFragment and CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter

I have an existing app displaying five different lists of entries from a database. It uses a left drawer to choose which list is displayed.

I would like to use ViewPager to these lists, but have a really hard time figuring out how this works. Unfortunately, I cannot find a tutorial that addresses this.

I have a MainActivity to which I connect a viewpagerAdapter

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Setting the viewpager
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_container_home);
    mPagerAdapter = new EntriesListPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

...
}

private class EntriesListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  ...


     @Override
     public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


         // What to put here???

         return view;
    }
}
```

I have a ListFragment class getting its data from a ResourceCursorAdapter (called EntriesCursorAdapter). It is a long class, so I give some parts to give you an idea.

```
public class EntriesListFragment extends ListFragment {

...


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    ...
        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            mEntriesCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            mEntriesCursorAdapter.swapCursor(Constants.EMPTY_CURSOR);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(STATE_URI);
            mShowFeedInfo = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_SHOW_FEED_INFO);
            mListDisplayDate = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_LIST_DISPLAY_DATE);

            mEntriesCursorAdapter = new EntriesCursorAdapter(getActivity(), mUri, Constants.EMPTY_CURSOR, mShowFeedInfo);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View inflateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry_list, container, true);

        if (mEntriesCursorAdapter != null) {
            setListAdapter(mEntriesCursorAdapter);
        }

        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        ...
    }

   public void setData(Uri uri, boolean showFeedInfo) {
       mUri = uri;
       mShowFeedInfo = showFeedInfo;

       mEntriesCursorAdapter = new EntriesCursorAdapter(getActivity(), mUri, Constants.EMPTY_CURSOR, mShowFeedInfo);

    }
```

Can you help me how to create five instances of the listfragment (with cursoradapter) and connect it to the ViewPager in the MainActivity? Any hint how to proceed is welcome.

**Update:** I noticed that the FragmentPagerAdapter is from the support.v4 library. If I am to use this, It looks like I have to use the ListFragment from support.v4 as well, including the LoaderManager. Unfortunately, the LoaderManager is not easily upgraded to support.v4. Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved. I will give the main pointers.

First, read this tutorial, because the given structure works. http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentpageradapter-example/

Second, check that all your imports are from the support.v4 library. This means the FragmentActivity (AppCompatActivity in the case above), ListFragment, Loader, LoaderManager and CursorLoader. I spent quite some time trying to figure out what was wrong with the code, while all the time I still had the Loader and CursorLoader from the wrong library.

Third, the MainActivity is where the FragmentPagerAdapter is placed, like:

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static final int ITEMS = 5;  // number of lists
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        // Setting the viewpager
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_container_home);
        mPagerAdapter = new EntriesListPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        ...
    }

    public class EntriesListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public EntriesListPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return EntriesListFragment.init(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Fourth, the ListFragment has to change. It has to be able to be used several times in order to support the number of different lists in the ViewPager. I will give the importants methods/elements.

```
public class EntriesListFragment extends ListFragment {
// Loader to get the data from database for the list. Called from startLoaders();
private final LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mEntriesLoader = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {...} 


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Getting the page number when created
    pageViewerFragmentNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry_list, container, false); // orig was 'true'
    mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityCreated");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Setting the adapter for each of the Feeds
    // The used feedId is the pageViewerFragmentNum + 1

    String FeedId = String.valueOf(pageViewerFragmentNum+1);
    mUri = EntryColumns.ENTRIES_FOR_FEED_CONTENT_URI(FeedId);

    // setting the adapter for the list
    mEntriesCursorAdapter = new EntriesCursorAdapter(getActivity(), mUri,
            Constants.EMPTY_CURSOR);
    setListAdapter(mEntriesCursorAdapter);
    startLoaders();
}

// Initialise the new listFragment for each Page. Notice the static!
public static EntriesListFragment init(int positie) {
    EntriesListFragment viewPagerFragmentList = new EntriesListFragment();
    // Supply val input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("val", positie);
    viewPagerFragmentList.setArguments(args);
    return viewPagerFragmentList;
}

private void startLoaders() { 
    LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    loaderManager.restartLoader(ENTRIES_LOADER_ID, null, mEntriesLoader);
}

}
```

Notice that the code given above is not complete. The tutorial mentioned earlier is, but I just tried to show you the main ingredients to get you started if you get stuck on this like I did.